# Integrating Umbraco and Intelligencia UrlRewriter

Tags: vb.net, url-rewriting, umbraco, umbraco7

I have used Intellegencia UrlRewriter for a while now.
I used it with  VB class that looks up the product Name and gets the relevant ID number to use for the querystring.
It works great.

How can I do the same thing in Umbraco?

I have thought of 1 way:
To use url structure of ~/products/product_name/ (which is really ~/products/product.aspx?id=XX) and add ~/products/* as a reserved folder and basically take this entire page out of Umbraco.

The problem is that my client would like the site structure to be ~/product_name/ (not in a subfolder). My problem is that I don't think I have any way to tell Umbraco not to handle these pages.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can inform umbraco to ignore paths with the following appSettings key in your web.config:

```
<appSettings> 
     ....
    <add key="umbracoReservedPaths" value="~/umbraco,~/install/,~/product_name/" />
```

This key is included in the web.config by default so you can search `umbracoReservedPaths` and you will find it. Simply add your path and umbraco will ignore it. You may also specify individual pages with the `umbracoReservedUrls` appSetting key.

Of note, you will see that in the /config/ folder there is a `UrlRewritting.config` for the urlrewritting.net rewritter already integrated into your umbraco install.